# Using orderby with Select() in lambda expression C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a variable which have 4 properties. How can I order this by Ids and then using this order for selecting ProductIds.

```
var products = await _festivalService.GetFestivalProductByProductIds(
    searchProductIds, searchModel.FestivalId);
var productIds = products.Select(x => x.ProductId).ToArray();
```

productIds Should be sorted descending base on Ids and then select productIds.

Answer (score 2):

what about `OrderByDescending` befor `Select`?

```
var productIds = products.OrderByDescending(x => x.ProductId)
                         .Select(x => x.ProductId).ToArray();
```